# Clean reading of HTML table with R

Tags: html, csv, database, r

I have some data under an HTML format and would like to import it in R. However, it seems that type inference is much less sophisticated than what exists with functions such as read.table. I am using the following workaround, which consists in reading the data table once, write it as a csv and re-import it.

```
# import raw data as HTML
require(XML)
raw_data <- readHTMLTable(doc = ".\\data\\mydata", 
                          header = T, 
                          as.data.frame = T)
# clean format and import

write.table(x = raw_data, file = ".\\temp.csv", quote = TRUE)
clean_data <- read.table(".\\temp.csv")

removeDots <- function(x)
{
  x <- gsub(pattern = "NULL", replacement = "", x = x, fixed = T)
  gsub(pattern = ".", replacement = "", x = x, fixed = T)
}

colnames(clean_data) <- lapply(X = colnames(clean_data), FUN = removeDots)
```

Per example, the following data is imported as a table of factors:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any better option ?

Comment: Which types are being falsely inferred? Kind of hard to tell without data to try.

Comment: It does not infer any type at all... There is the argument elFun that I can play with, but it is hard to reproduce the parsing of read.table

Comment: Apparently, `doc` can be *a character vector containing the HTML content to parse and process.*, so you should be able to make a small reproducible example by dumping the source html into a string: `x <- "<html>...</html>"`. Thanks.

Comment: @flodel I added some sample

Comment: Good example, thanks. Have you considered the `colClasses` option? E.g.  `x <- readHTMLTable(doc, header = FALSE, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "integer"))`?

Comment: @flodel yes, but it was just a sample of the data. With a large number of columns (which is the case, about 100) it quickly becomes painful...

Comment: The `readHTMLTable` behavior clearly is suprising and disappointing. A possible alternative to `XML` is the `rvest` package and its `html_table` function. The examples provided in the doc show that it does differentiate between data types. Otherwise, if you need to stick with the `XML` package, I'd say your idea of writing/reading via a temp file is good and what I would have used as well.

Comment: The "imported as a table of factors" is because the following parameter was not set on read: `stringsAsFactors = F`